# migrate Apache OFBiz from Apache Derby to mysql

Tags: mysql, derby, ofbiz

I am using ofbiz in my organization. I want to migrate ofbiz from derby to MySQL.
I refer the steps from
(https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/How+to+migrate+OfBiz+from+Derby+to+MySQL+database) here, but at the i got stuck at the end.
At the end when I type (java -jar ofbiz.jar -install) this command I am getting an exception,

C:\Users\sagar_vinod_khanke\Sagar\Apache OFBiz\Ofbiz\13.07>java -jar ofbiz.jar -
install

Exception in thread "main" org.ofbiz.base.start.StartupException: Couldn't not f
etch config instance

```
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.init(Start.java:202)
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:127)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot load configuration properties : org/ofbiz
/base/start/-install.properties

```
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Config.getPropertiesFile(Config.java:229)
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Config.readConfig(Config.java:297)
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Config.getInstance(Config.java:58)
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.init(Start.java:200)
    ... 1 more
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

don't use - with install.
See revised Step-V

**Step-V**

```
1. Run the following command from command prompt:
java -jar ofbiz.jar install
2. Start OfBiz
3. Use webtools to import all data from XML:
a. Navigate to http://localhost:8080/catalog/
b. Go to Applications>WebTools
c. Go to section 'Entity XML Tools' and click the link 'XML Data Import Dir' -> In the 'Absolute directory path:' enter the full path of the directory where you exported the data in Step - II
```